# Set value of a Nested field in reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

in my application that uses reflection i have two classes

```
public class FirstClass
{
   public string someVar;
   public SecondClass second;   
   public FirstClass()
   {
      second = new SecondClass();
   }
} 

public class SecondClass
{
   public string anotherVar;
}
```

in my main program i have an instance of FirstClass

```
MainProgram()
{
   Object obj = InstanceOfFirstClass() // reflected instance of first class
}
```

How do i set the value of anotherVar inside obj?

Comment: Are the fields really public?

Comment: Yes fields are public, i am thinking of using something like this

   FieldInfo field = obj.GetType().GetField("anotherVar");
   // then set the value
   field.SetValue(obj,newValue);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With public fields, this is relatively simple:

```
    object obj = InstanceOfFirstClass();
    object second = obj.GetType().GetField("second").GetValue(obj);
    second.GetType().GetField("anotherVar").SetValue(second, "newValue");
```

If the fields were not public, then you would need to use an overload of `GetField` that takes a `BindingFlags` argument with the `NonPublic` flag set.

In .Net 4, you could just use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic obj = InstanceOfFirstClass();
obj.second.anotherVar = "newValue";
```

Comment: Thanks mike the first answer worked just fine :) im using .NET 3.5 so there is no dynamic.

Comment: This answer is FALSE, it WILL throw a nullreference exception since "second" in obj.second.anotherVar is not instantiated!

Comment: @Best_Where_Gives In the context of the code in the OP, `second` is initialized by the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the example which reads the field and set a value of the field via reflection in
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z33zd7h.aspx.
In your case it will look like

```
    Object myObject = InstanceOfFirstClass() // reflected instance of first class
    Type myType = typeof(FirstClass);
    FieldInfo myFieldInfo = myType.GetField("second", 
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance); 

    // Change the field value using the SetValue method. 
    myFieldInfo.SetValue(myObject , //myobject is the reflected instance
    value);//value is the object which u want to assign to the field);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply,

I cannot use Type myType = typeof(FirstClass) because FirstClass will be known only during runtime.

Comment: then you can do something like Type myType = myObject.GetType();